# Refresh the UI of Windows Form

Tags: winforms

I'm working on an old project that supports Windows Forms.
This project contains some ResourceManager for the support of a few localizations. The idea is that you call ResourceManager["SomeResource"] instead of Resource.SomeResource and it returns you a localized string.
And these localized strings are used in the code of the initialization of the form. For example, you have Form1, and in Form1.Design.cs there is some code like this:

```
Label label1 = new Label();
label1.Text = ResourceManager["SomeResource"];
```

So the label will be created with an already localized string in the Text.
And we need to add the functionality of changing the UI language without reloading the Form.

1. We can just set the every Text property of every controls again. But it's a lot of code, the form contains a lot of controls.
2. We can call the Form.InitializeComponents(), this method will recreate all controls with new localized strings, but in some cases, it works slowly because it reloads some big data again.

Is there some other way to refresh all UI controls and get the new localized strings? Do Windows Forms support some mechanism like Binding in the WPF to create the "connection" between the Text properties and localized resources?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can achieve this by use of `Invalidate()` either on the form itself or on a container control that your other controls may be encompassed by.

Comment: Tried, but it doesn't work.